# Is there a Vulkan command equivalent to the synchronization guarantees from separate commandbuffers in the same queue submit?

Tags: graphics, synchronization, vulkan

I have a Vulkan backend for my renderer that uses multiple command buffers -- some for uploads, one per raster pass, one per compute pass, etc.

I'd like to take more advantage of Vulkan's `SYNCHRONIZATION_VALIDATION` extension.  From the [Current Feature Set section of the synchronization_usage docs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/blob/main/docs/synchronization_usage.md#current-feature-set):

> Hazard detection for memory usage for commands within the *same* command buffer.

So I've changed my renderer and engine to allow me to (optionally, during debugging) emit all my commands into a single command buffer, in order, from a single thread.  The hope is that I might enable the layer to detect more issues this way.

However, now I'm detecting issues that I believe are covered by "[Implicit Synchronization Guarantees](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-implicit)" or similar that I had when I had separate command buffers.

Is there any command (e.g. a specific `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` or `vkCmdPipelineBarrier2KHR`) or synchronization primitive that either *exactly* matches the execution/memory/visibility guarantees that I'd naturally get from separate commandbuffers within a single queue submission, or only *slightly exceeds* them?  Something I could add where previously I had `vkEndCommandBuffer` and `vkBeginCommandBuffer`?

Or, more generally, are there better strategies for improving `SYNCHRONIZATION_VALIDATION`'s ability to see issues?

Comment: "*now I'm detecting issues that I believe are covered by "Implicit Synchronization Guarantees" or similar that I had when I had separate command buffers.*" No such things exist. There are implicit guarantees, but *none of them* care about CB boundaries specifically. They may care about batch boundaries or submit command boundaries, but I don't know of any such rules that care about CB boundaries. Can you go into more detail surrounding what *specifically* you are doing that you think are covered by implicit synchronization?

Comment: @NicolBolas _"There are implicit guarantees, but none of them care about CB boundaries specifically."_ -- that's... actually super useful to me, and I'm happy to upvote/accept that as an answer.  I think I can sort out the issues I'm seeing one by one, knowing that.  The first example is a RAW hazard between a `vkCommandCopyBuffer` that populates our "transient draw index/vertex buffer" early in the frame, and our UI pass that uses that in `vkCmdDrawIndexed` late in the frame.  We submit no related BufferBarriers currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is *no* special synchronization behavior given to the boundaries of command buffers *specifically*. Submit commands get some special boundary treatment (mostly pertaining to host memory operations), and batches within submit commands might have some implicit synchronization relative to other batches.

But I don't know of any form of implicit synchronization that happens between CBs *within* the same batch.

Comment: Aha, the "as if they had all been recorded into a single primary command buffer" language here is nicely explicit: https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#fundamentals-queueoperation